# MySQL cursor based pagination with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have some table that I want to query using cursor based pagination, but it needs to apply for multiple columns.

Let's take a simplified example of using 2 columns - I fetch the first page like this:

```sql
SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_1, column_2
LIMIT 10
```

After I get the results, I can fetch the next page based on the last row. Let's say the last row was `column_1 = 5, column_2 = 8`. I'd like to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM table_name
WHERE column_1 > 5 AND column_2 > 8
ORDER BY column_1, column_2
LIMIT 10
```

But this is obviously wrong. It would filter out a row that has `column_1 = 5, column_2 = 9` (because of the filter on `column_1`) or a row that has `column_1 = 6, column_2 = 6` (because of the filter on `column_2`)

I can do something like this to avoid the problem:

```sql
SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM table_name
WHERE column_1 > 5
OR (column_1 = 5 AND column_2 > 8)
ORDER BY column_1, column_2
LIMIT 10
```

But this becomes very cumbersome and error prone for more than 2 columns...

Also, my use case includes columns of multiple types (`INT UNSIGNED` and `BINARY`), but all are comparable

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope.  You are stuck with that complex `WHERE`.  But it is efficient.  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If column `Column_1` is unique, we could just do:

```
 WHERE Column_1 > :last_retrieved_value
 ORDER BY Column_1
 LIMIT 20
```

From the question, it appears that `Column_1` is not unique, but the `(Column_1,Column_2)` tuple is unique.

The general form for a "next page" query, ordering by those two columns, using the last retrieved values for those two columns, would be...

```
    (Column1,Column2) > (:lrv_col1,:lrv_col2)
```

(lrv = value saved from the last row retrieved by the previous query)

To write that condition in MySQL, we can do that like you have shown:

```
 WHERE t.Column_1 > :lrv_col1
    OR ( t.Column_1 = :lrv_col1 AND t.Column_2 > :lrv_col2 )
```

Or, we could write it like this, which I prefer, because there's much less of a chance for MySQL to get confused by the OR condition and use the wrong index...

```
 WHERE t.Column_1 >= :lrv_col1
       AND ( t.Column_1 > :lrv_col1 OR t.Column_2 > :lrv_col2 )
 ORDER BY t.Column_1, t.Column_2
 LIMIT n
```

To extend that to *three* columns, to check the condition...

```
  (c1,c2,c3) > (:lrv1,:lrv2,:lrv3)
```

We handle it just like in the case of two columns, handling `c1` first, breaking it out just like the two columns:

```
 WHERE c1 >= :lrv1
       AND ( c1 > :lrv1 OR ( ... ) )
 ORDER BY c1, c2, c3
 LIMIT n
```

And now that placeholder `...` (where would have had just the check on `c2` before, is really again just another case of two columns. We need to check: `(c2,c3) > (lrv2,lrv3)`, so we can expand that using the same pattern:

```
 WHERE c1 >= :lrv1
       AND ( c1 > :lrv1 OR ( c2 >= :lrv2 
                             AND ( c2 > :lrv2 OR c3 > :lrv3 )
                           )
           )
 ORDER BY c1,c2,c3
 LIMIT n
```

I agree that the expansion may look a little messy. But it does follow a very regular pattern. Similarly, we could express the condition on *four* columns...

```
 (c1,c2,c3,c4) > (:lrv1,:lrv2,:lrv3,:lrv4)
```

We just take what we have for the three columns, and we need to expand **`c3 > :lrv3`** to replace it with **`( c3 >= :lrv3 AND ( c3 > :lrv3 OR c4 > :lrv4 ) )`**

```
 WHERE c1 >= :lrv1
       AND ( c1 > :lrv1 OR ( c2 >= :lrv2 
                             AND ( c2 > :lrv2 OR ( c3 >= :lrv3
                                                   AND ( c3 > :lrv3 OR c4 > :lrv4 )
                                                 )
                                 )
                           )
           )
 ORDER BY c1,c2,c3,c4
 LIMIT n
```

As an aid the the future reader, I would comment this block, and indicate the intent ...

```
 -- (c1,c2,c3,c4) > (lr1,lr2,lr3,lr4)
```

And it would be nice if MySQL would allow us to express the comparison just like that. Unfortunately, we have to expand that into something MySQL understands.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

I tried using the simple "tuple" comparison and it worked (MySQL 5.6). Trying to run some `EXPLAIN` queries to see if it's better than the expanded version...

Comment: Ha!  I didn't know that MySQL supported that tuple comparison syntax! That'd be a whole lot easier...  `(c1,c2,c3) > (r1,r2,r3)` than the expansion. Yes, check the EXPLAIN plan... we'd want MySQL to use an index range scan operation, with c1,c2,c3 as the leading columns.

Comment: @spencer7593 - It's a lot easier, but it is sloooow, since the Optimizer does not take know about it.  (8.0 _might_ have this fixed.)

Comment: The complex alternative has the added flexibility of mixing `ASC` and `DESC` by using  `>` and `<` operators together.

Comment: What is the name of the tuple comparison (a,b,c) > (x,z,y) syntax? I'm not finding it in Postgres documentation.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky:  in MySQL, it's just the comparison operator   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than  In PostgreSQL, I don't think a tuple is considered a datatype where a comparison "makes sense" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 ! the comparison operator on tuples definitely seems to work in Postgres, for example: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/141#issuecomment-406006229.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky: looks like the `ROW()` constructor is implicit in PostgreSQL ie. `(a,b,c)>(x,y,z)` is equivalent to `ROW(a,b,c) > ROW(x,y,z)` ... as far as what the comparison operator is called, it's just a comparison operator, just like it is with any other data types where a comparison operator "makes sense"

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thanks a lot. Looks like it's documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON: "For the <, <=, > and >= cases, the row elements are compared left-to-right, stopping as soon as an unequal or null pair of elements is found. If either of this pair of elements is null, the result of the row comparison is unknown (null); otherwise comparison of this pair of elements determines the result."

Comment: Regarding your first example, column_1 being unique: is it enough? I mean, even if it's not sorted by that column and that column does not follow an incremental pattern like increasing number? (I'm thinking about uuid here)

Comment: @CyrilN.  you are right. uniqueness is not enough. what really matters is that `ORDER BY` clause, so rows are returned in a sorted (deterministic) order. the comparisons in the where clause are designed to exclude rows earlier or before the last retrieve values, the `ORDER BY` sorts the rows, and from that whole set, the `LIMIT` chops the set so we are getting the "next N rows". then we retain the values from the last row we retrieved, to use that in the next query.