# 100k records Mysql database with errors after import

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, http-status-code-404

I have a database problem, when it's huge. I'll describe: it's very simple - created by third-party app and have only fields in one table: 'page' and 'data' - about page (url) and data.
So it's work perfect on low pages count ~ 5000, but it work with errors on 100k pages. When i open index page on site or 2-nd, 3-rd pages  - it opens correctly, but if i'll open 55321 page - i have 404 error.

My config is fast for 100к-pages db: vps with ssd aтв nginx + php+fpm on it. Memory is ok, cpu is ok.

**1.** May be it indexes after import and i have to wait for it?

**2.** Or may be i have to create indexes manualy? Can anyone help with command.

**3.** My db starts with this:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain_com` (
    `page` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `data` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`page`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

May be it need to switched to MYISAM Engine to improve indexing?

==== Added a code from sample page (product.php in my case) ====

```
<?
$n = $_GET["n"];
if (isset($_GET["ctgfolder"])) {
    $ctgfolder = $_GET["ctgfolder"];
} else {
    $ctgfolder = '';
}

if (strlen($ctgfolder) > 0) {
    $fn = "$ctgfolder/product-$n.txt";
} else {
    $fn = "product-$n.txt";
}
if (file_exists($fn) == true) {
    $file = fopen($fn, 'r');
    $tx   = fread($file, filesize($fn));
    fclose($file);

} else {
    if (file_exists("dbinfo.php") == true) {
        include "dbinfo.php";
        $site_encoding = 'utf8';
        $msconnect     = mysql_connect($mshost, $msuser, $mspassword);
        mysql_select_db($msname, $msconnect);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        if ($site_encoding != 'utf8') {
            mysql_query("SET character_set_client = $site_encoding");
            mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = $site_encoding");
            mysql_query("SET character_set_results = $site_encoding");
        }

        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `domain_com` WHERE page='$fn'");
        if ($res) {
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                $tx = $row['data'];

                $file = fopen($fn, 'w');
                fwrite($file, $tx);
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
        mysql_close($msconnect);
    }
}



$k = 0;
$p = strpos($tx, '{#');
while ($p !== false) {
    $p2 = strpos($tx, '#}', $p);
    $im = substr($tx, $p + 2, $p2 - ($p + 2));
    $k++;

    //--------------



    if (file_exists("dmcr.php")) {
        include "dmcr.php";
    } else {
        include "../dmcr.php";
    }

    //-------------
    $mcr[$k] = $im;
    $p       = strpos($tx, '{#', $p2 + 2);
}

if (file_exists("template_page.php")) {
    include "template_page.php";
} else {
    include "../template_page.php";
}

    ?>
```

==== And this is index.php ======

```
 $fn="index_page.txt"; 
if(file_exists($fn)==true){
$file=fopen($fn,'r'); 
$tx=fread($file,filesize($fn));
fclose($file); 

} else {
if(file_exists("dbinfo.php")==true){
include "dbinfo.php";
$site_encoding='utf8';
$msconnect = mysql_connect($mshost, $msuser, $mspassword);
mysql_select_db($msname, $msconnect);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if($site_encoding!='utf8'){
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = $site_encoding");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = $site_encoding");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = $site_encoding");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `domain_com` WHERE page='$fn'"); 
if($res){ 
    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $tx=$row['data'];

    $file=fopen($fn,'w'); 
    fwrite($file,$tx);
    fclose($file);
    }
}
mysql_close($msconnect);
}
}


$k=0;
$p=strpos($tx,'{#');
while($p!==false){
$p2=strpos($tx,'#}',$p);
$im=substr($tx,$p+2,$p2-($p+2));
$k++;

//--------------


include "dmcr.php";

//-------------
$mcr[$k]=$im;
$p=strpos($tx,'{#',$p2+2);
}


include "template_page.php";
?>
```

=== ctg.php =====

```
<?
$c = $_GET["c"];
$p = $_GET["p"];
if (strlen($c) == 0) {
    $c = 1;
}
if (strlen($p) == 0 or is_numeric($p) == false) {
    $p = 1;
}


$fn = "ctg-$c-$p.txt";

if (file_exists($fn) == true) {
    $file = fopen($fn, 'r');
    $tx   = fread($file, filesize($fn));
    fclose($file);

} else {
    if (file_exists("dbinfo.php") == true) {
        include "dbinfo.php";
        $site_encoding = 'utf8';
        $msconnect     = mysql_connect($mshost, $msuser, $mspassword);
        mysql_select_db($msname, $msconnect);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        if ($site_encoding != 'utf8') {
            mysql_query("SET character_set_client = $site_encoding");
            mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = $site_encoding");
            mysql_query("SET character_set_results = $site_encoding");
        }

        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `domain_com` WHERE page='$fn'");
        if ($res) {
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                $tx = $row['data'];

                $file = fopen($fn, 'w');
                fwrite($file, $tx);
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
        mysql_close($msconnect);
    }
}



$k = 0;
$p = strpos($tx, '{#');
while ($p !== false) {
    $p2 = strpos($tx, '#}', $p);
    $im = substr($tx, $p + 2, $p2 - ($p + 2));
    $k++;

    //--------------



    if (file_exists("dmcr.php")) {
        include "dmcr.php";
    } else {
        include "../dmcr.php";
    }


    //-------------
    $mcr[$k] = $im;
    $p       = strpos($tx, '{#', $p2 + 2);
}

include "template_page.php";
?>
```

=== In template page we have a template.php with includes =====

Comment: need to see the code for "index page"

Comment: You need to post some actual code. But I do smell pagination via `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` which requires mysql to compile as much of the result set as it needs to scroll through. This results in 'quick' results for low pages numbers, and 'hey my server died' for high page numbers. Solving this problem is quite [non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017054/mysql-cursor-based-pagination-with-multiple-columns).

Comment: Added come code (don't be scarry :)

Comment: "it work with errors on 100k pages" - what errors?  And you said you had only 5000 pages??

Comment: Do _not_ switch to MyISAM.

Comment: Do not use the antiquated `mysql_*` API; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  What version of PHP?  What version of MySQL?

Comment: Is `SELECT * FROM `domain_com` WHERE page='$fn'` the only `SELECT`?  That should work quickly even for a billion pages.